# Spring data cassandra (v3.3.1): how to add codec?

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data

I use `spring-data-cassandra:3.3.1` and try to apply `TimestampCodec`. Documentation says that all codecs should be added through `CodecRegistry`, but says nothing about a way to access it.

I use config like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories("com.example.repo")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration
```

...but I don't understand how could I provide codecs.

Any ideas / examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `getSessionBuilderConfigurer` inside your `CassandraConfig` class:

```
@Override
protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
    return (sessionBuilder) -> sessionBuilder.addTypeCodecs(ExtraTypeCodecs.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP_UTC);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, Aliaksandr. There's very little info online as far as how to add your own custom codecs using Cassandra with Spring. Thanks for the contribution. This helped. The only difference was that I was required to do `(cqlSessionBuilder)` instead of `(sessionBuilder)`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what @Aliaksandr Hamayunau said above:

Best practice in Spring is to default to autoconfiguration. With that said, the Spring `ApplicationContext` looks for the single name of a Bean. You can override autoconfigured Beans by creating your own Bean with the same name in your custom configuration class and Spring will use your Bean. In a custom Cassandra configuration you can create a Bean of CqlSession, customize your Cassandra configuration and pass your custom `TypeCodecs` at init time:

```
@Bean
public CqlSession cqlSession() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException() {
    return CqlSession.builder()
            .addTypeCodecs(new CustomCodec))
            .addContactPoint(contactPoint())
            ...
}
```

At runtime:

```
MutableCodecRegistry registry = 
    (MutableCodecRegistry) session.getContext().getCodecRegistry();

registry.register(new CustomCodec());
```

Here's the docs on custom TypeCodecs https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/custom_codecs/